# How can I do a one to one concat for my data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I scrape a website for ps4 games and it gives me the brand, products name and shipping info and price.
The output I'm looking for is two tables with two columns each. in the first table the columns are product_name and brand, and second table columns are product_name and shipping. then I want to concat those two data frame.

````
#!pip install beautifulsoup4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import re

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# file
filename = "products.csv"

d = defaultdict(list)

# fill dict
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    d['brand'].append(brand)
    d['product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    
# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv file
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)

# choose rows where shipping is less than 5.99
print(df[df['shipping'] > 200]) ```
````

Comment: `Now I want to ...` Which part are you having trouble with? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#indexing-selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#indexing-selection)

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired output is?  Currently there is only one dataframe in this code.

Comment: the output I'm looking for is two tables with two columns each. in the first table the columns are product_name and brand, and second table columns are product_name  and shipping. then I want to merge those two data frame. I tried merging them but it didn't work.